# Validates presence of THIS or THAT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where the user is prompt to enter a title and either `:this` or `:that`. A user can't enter both fields.

```
<% f.input :title%>
<% f.input :this %>
<% f.input :that%>
```

for my `:title` i have in my Model

```
validates :title, :presence => true
```

How can i pass a validation for `either :this or :that`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
validates :that, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new {this.blank?}
validates :this, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new {that.blank?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just the first line be sufficient?

```
validates :that, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new {this.blank?}
```

If 'this' is blank and so is 'that', the first line would fail validation, so you wouldn't need the second line.